# Distance measurement through back of car window

Tags: distance

I'm contemplating whether its possible to measure the distance to the next car behind me in some easy way.

What I want to do is simple, if the car behind my car is closer than 10m, turn on a rather annoying (but not blinding) light pointing at them.

So, what is the best way to measure the distance to an object through a window. The accuracy needs to be in the region of ~10m +/- 1 meter.

Comment: I do it optically with a mechanical feedback actuator for the light. I.e., I look in my read view mirror and turn on my fog lights. 10m is a bit of a long distance for this kind of thing. 1m maybe it could be of some use, but 10m?! And what isn't blinding to you could be blinding to the old lady driving the 1975 maxi behind you...

Comment: Also, I don't know where you live, but in the UK there are [strict laws governing what lights can be shown on a vehicle.](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1989/1796/regulation/11/made)

Comment: @Majenko Well it does not have to be lights, could be a LED sign with a well chosen word.

Comment: Last time I checked LEDs were a form of light... sign shaped or not.

Comment: Just checked, in my country a low power white or yellow LED sign is legal as long as the text does not scroll.

Comment: ... or offend the person behind you to such an extent that the ram you off the road. ;)

Comment: Since the question doesn't mention Arduinos at all, I'll migrate this to Electronics Stack Exchange where I am confident they will have some useful suggestions.

Comment: If 10 m distance is enough depends on the speed of both cars. While waiting at a red traffic light with zero speed, 1 m distance is no problem. When both cars are part of a vers slow traffic jam the annoying light should be disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Through solid object such as a window consider using [Micropower Impulse Radar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micropower_impulse_radar) developed at Lawrence Livermore National Laboratory and used in stud-finders, for security and in vehicles.

Comment: Do you have any links where one might acquire such a thing, could not find much for sale anywhere with those keywords.

Comment: Actually there are a number of ways to do this.  MIR is probably the better as I think it is used for auto back up sensors.  But you could use LIDAR or even Computer Vision (OpenCV).  However, with OpenCV you will likely have to abandon low power platforms in favor of full operating systems like the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: No.  I'm not sure why.  I thought LLL had listed licensees at one point.  Regardless, I'm not convinced this is an economical solution (most people who buy Arduinos don't want to spends 5  to 10 times that on a sensor) as it sounds as complex as LIDAR to manage (time of flight stuff).

Answer (score 0):

The system should use the British "Only a fool breaks the 2-second rule" algorithm. That is, the safe distance between vehicles is 2 s. That means you need a velocity input into your system so that you can calculate the separation by \$ \Delta t = \frac {s}{v} \$ where \$ \Delta t \$ is the gap between the cars (s), \$ s \$ is the distance (m) and \$ v \$ is the velocity (m/s). The vehicle speed may be available from the CANBUS or from a GPS interface.

For sensing you have the choice of radar devices or possibly ultrasonic. Ultrasonic would have to be mounted externally (it won't work through glass) and so would have to be waterproof.